# Where is mass defect in nuclear fusion?

Tags: energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, fusion, binding-energy

The hydrogen is one proton and the helium is two protons and two neutrons. Neutron is a little heavier than the proton. But there is something strange. Where is the mass defection? As a result, the helium should be heavier than the sum of four protons, but it is not.

So I guess the reason for binding energy. But I can't understand.

In the picture, the helium's binding energy is bigger than hydrogen's.

And particle's mass ( 4 protons < 2 protons and 2 neutrons) and binding energy (hydrogen < helium)

Through the E=mc^2, isn't right the helium's mass bigger than the sum of 4 hydrogens?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusions relating mass defect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75672/)

Comment: Rather than just looking at the final mass,  you probably should research the **process** by which, e.g.  , two Deuterium atoms could become one He atom  https://www.cyberphysics.co.uk/Q&A/KS5/Nuclear/fusion/fusionMC_ANS.html

Comment: A quick google search and back of the envelope calculation resulted in a difference of about $-0.029$ amu between mass of helium and sum of its constituents.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of [binding energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy) is the wrong way round. It is the energy required to disassemble a composite system, not the energy required to assemble it. So the fact that the binding energy per nucleon for helium is greater than for hydrogen/deuterium means that it requires a net addition of energy to split a helium nucleus into two deuterium nuclei. Conversely, energy is released when two deuterium nuclei fuse to form a helium nucleus.